# Como somar um campo de objetos retornados do firebase ( vuejs + firebase )

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, electron, erp

Ola , estou tentando desenvolver uma plataforma ERP com vuejs utilizando o firebase como solução de armazenamento , estou tentando somar todos os campos 'valor' dos documentos da coleção 'despesa' que carrega os campos 'Nome' 'Valor' 'Data' 'Descrição' para apresentar um total
esse é meu codigo para pegar os dados do firebase:

```js
ReceberDados:function(){
            fb.DesRef.get().then((querySnapshot)=> {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                   var result = doc.data();
                            console.log(result)
                   
                })
            })
        }
```

como resultado o console eu tenho
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso somar todos os campos 'Valor' ?
( dicas para o projeto tbm são bem vindas )

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando javascript você pode fazer um `map` para retornar apenas o valor e depois fazer um `reduce` para somá-los
Veja esse exemplo:

```
let usuarios = [
    { nome: 'Diego', Valor: 23, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Gabriel', Valor: 15, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Lucas', Valor: 30, empresa: 'Facebook' },
];
const valorTotal = usuarios.map(u => u.Valor).reduce((total, valor) => total + valor);
     console.log(valorTotal);
```